# How to use FME to parse .txt file to publish content to REST Interface?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, arcgis-10.2, fme-form

I have a, from my point of view, complex question, which can be hopefully answered by some  of you. Firstly some general information. I'm using

- Windows Server 2012
- FME Desktop and Server 2013
- ArcGIS Server 10.2

My plan: I want to use a Web Harvesting program, which searches on OpenData-Sites for accessible WMS Services, which I want to integrate in my WebMap. This application is already working. It searches for available WMS Services using defined filters and stores the information in a .txt file. So the .txt file stores all the necessary the WMS-Links
(a link could look like this:

- http://gateway.hamburg.de/OGCFassade/DE_HH_WMS_INSPIRE_A3_4_Bodennutzung_lokal.aspx?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0

or this

- http://www.geoportal.rlp.de/mapbender/php/wms.php?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&layer_id=32327

Now I want to use FME Desktop/server, which reads/parsed the lines of the .txt file (the lines are the WMS links) and after that, FME should publish these links to the FME or ArcGIS Server Rest Interface, where they are accessible for using it in a webmap.

So....firstly my question would be: Is this possible?
And secondly: If it is possible, how to realize it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck? Are you just trying to extract the WMS links?  You could easily use a Text Reader and filter out lines which match an address or part of an address or some pattern using Regular Expressions.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Up to know, I haven't made any progress. I'm quite new to FME, so everything is a challenge. I would assume that the following workflow is the right one?!: Firstly extracting the links, and secondly publishing (however) to ArcGIS Server/ FME Server Rest Interface. Maybe you have some "keywords" for the Toolbox gallery, where I can start? Btw: Is the targetted solution a possible scenario?

Comment: I've never used FME Server, so I don't know what's involved in publishing.  If you want to extract links from the text files, just use a Tester transformer.  FME also has WMS readers which might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Your better option might be FME Desktop/Server 2014 [due 15/01/2014]

This a quick workspace that is using 2014 (Beta).

[image]

This loads a populated csv every hour [at 2014 this could be a real-time trigger]

If there is new content this is then inserted to a POSTGRES Database (for better file management, control).
Runs a workspace to populate your wms (I do not know your setup for arcgis server but the wms source is updated.)
If this fails for any reason it emails you immediately.

I am sure there is a faster way (Safe Employees are on this GIS-SE community)

I think the best link so far is 
http://fmepedia.safe.com/topic/Real-Time-Data-Processing
(WEBSOCKETS is the future for real-time processing).

Useful links

http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Workspace-Notifications-Part-1

http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Workspace-notifications-Part-2

http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Workspace-notifications-Part-3